# Linq and DBNull - Getting error

Tags: c#, linq, null, ienumerable, dbnull

I'm getting an error when selecting from a rows.AsEnumerable(). I am using the following code...

```
var rows = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable();
                trafficData = rows.Select(row => new tdDataDC
                {
                    CalculationCount = row.Field<Int64>("biCalculationCountSeqID")
                    , Zone = row.Field<Int16>("siFkZoneId")
                    , Miles = row.Field<decimal>("dcMiles")
                    , Plaza = row.Field<Int16>("siFkPlazaId")
                    , VehicleCount = row.Field<int>("iVehicleCount")


                });
```

Most of the time it works well, but when there are NULLS in the database I'm getting this error "Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Int16'. Please use a nullable type.."
How can I correct this? I don't want my datacontracts to have Nullable types, I'd like to use a ternary or something, and if a value is NULL, just use 0. Is this possible?

Thanks for any help,
~ck

Answer (score 11):

You could always add another extension method (untested):

```
   public static T FieldOrDefault<T>(this DataRow row, string columnName)
   {
       return row.IsNull(columnName) ? default(T) : row.Field<T>(columnName);   
   }
```

Then your callsite looks like:

```
var rows = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable();
                trafficData = rows.Select(row => new tdDataDC
                {
                    CalculationCount = row.FieldOrDefault<Int64>("biCalculationCountSeqID")
                    , Zone = row.FieldOrDefault<Int16>("siFkZoneId")
                    , Miles = row.FieldOrDefault<decimal>("dcMiles")
                    , Plaza = row.FieldOrDefault<Int16>("siFkPlazaId")
                    , VehicleCount = row.FieldOrDefault<int>("iVehicleCount")


                });
```

Comment: I like Marc's answer, but just to get another way of doing it, you could change the value types to be nullable (short? long? etc) and then coalesce, so something like row.Field<short?>("foo") ?? 0

Comment: BTW, rather than doing 2 row calls, if T is always a value type, you could do row.Field<Nullable<T>>(columnName) ?? default(T) although I doubt it's worth the hassle if you also use reference types :)

Answer (score 7):

Here is how you test for nulls...

```
Plaza = row.IsNull("siFkPlazaId") ? 0 : row.Field<int>("siFkPlazaId")
```

Answer (score 4):

If your property is nullable you can do this as well;

```
Plaza = row.Field<int16?>("siFkPlazaId")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty fond of the `??` operator:

```
CalculationCount = row.Field<Int64?>("biCalculationCountSeqID") ?? 0
                , Zone = row.Field<Int16?>("siFkZoneId") ?? 0
                , Miles = row.Field<decimal?>("dcMiles") ?? 0.0m
                , Plaza = row.Field<Int16?>("siFkPlazaId") ?? 0
                , VehicleCount = row.Field<int>("iVehicleCount") 0;
```